# Does working for a prestigious company help in a PhD application?

Tags: phd, application

Does working for a prestigious company help in a PhD application? For example, suppose one does interesting work while at a prestigious company. Would this help an application?

Comment: What is a "prestigious" company?

Comment: This almost certainly depends on your field.  What department(s) are you thinking of applying to?

Comment: @ravi-paul Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is "probably." The long answer is "it depends."

Admission to a graduate program is almost solely dependent on how well you impress that department's graduate admissions committee (assuming you meet any minimum admissions standards: grades, GRE, etc). If they attach value to your work in industry, it'll help you out immensely. If they don't, it probably won't hurt you.

This [Kaplan page](http://www.kaptest.com/GRE/Get-into-Grad-School/Build-a-Great-Application/inside-the-admission-committee.html) outlines the general process.

Answer (score 3):

If your work at the prestigious company involved a demonstration of your intellectual and/or research prowess, then yes, it'll probably help. If your work was mostly grunt work, then it's unlikely to make a large impact.

Answer (score 1):

Except if you are in a recognized inner lab of a big company, it will probably not help, and not hurt. Working may help if you do something that proves that you have skills useful to research work, that's all.